# How can I automate this code to input the computername from a txt. list?

Tags: command-line, command

```
sc \\computername  query box
sc \\computername  start box
sc \\computername  query crystal
sc \\computername  start crystal


taskkill /s computername  /im crystal.exe /f
taskkill /s computername  /im box.exe /f
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
@echo off

for /f "tokens=*" %%F in (list.txt) do (
    echo sc \\%%F  query box
    echo sc \\%%F  start box
    echo sc \\%%F  query crystal
    echo sc \\%%F  start crystal


    echo taskkill /s %%F  /im crystal.exe /f
    echo taskkill /s %%F  /im box.exe /f
)
pause
```

Comment: write this commands into a batch file , example `notepad automate.cmd`. Save the file and exit from notepad. Than execute the batch file. At the command prompt write `automate`

Comment: I ran this in CMD but got an error can you tell me how to use it ? Sorry but I am new to this.